# Linked questions on the sidebar is not catching all links in comments?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, hyperlinks

I was looking at the links on **[Anyone have some links to “easy to read” resources for a DND newbie?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4943/anyone-have-some-links-to-easy-to-read-resources-for-a-dnd-newbie)** and I can plainly see two links to questions in the comments, but only one of them shows up in the `Linked` sidebar.

Comment: +1 I tried your experiment, and you seem to be right!

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in how the linked questions were being determined.

A fix will be pushed in tomorrow's build and I'll update the links using the new code.